# Missing type annotation for a type parameter declared in function type that was implicitly instantiated at call of combineReducers

Tags: javascript, redux, instantiation, flowtype, implicit

I am getting the following error on combineReducers in Redux now.

Missing type annotation for `A`. `A` is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at call of `combineReducers` [2].

The code looks as follows, but is ocurring in all of my reducers that use combineReducers.

```
export default combineReducers({
  status: ((state: boolean = true, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'START_SESSION':
      case 'REFRESH_AUTH_SUCCEEDED':
      case 'SIGN_IN_FAILED':
      case 'SIGN_OUT':
        return false;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }: Reducer<*>),
});
```

I believe it is because of this type definition in the Redux flow-types

```
declare export function combineReducers<O: Object, A>(reducers: O): 
       CombinedReducer<$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>, A>;
```

I believe this has to do with the release of Flow, version 0.85.0 which introduced some stuff having to do with "implicit instantiations."

I read this article on Medium by the FLow's own Sam Goldman and that is how I came to this conclusion.
https://medium.com/flow-type/asking-for-required-annotations-64d4f9c1edf8

I was able to get the error to go away by doing the following which is my attempt at implementing something like the articles mention of the solution "providing explicit type argument to the function call."

```
export default combineReducers<Object, Action>({
  status: ((state: boolean = true, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'START_SESSION':
      case 'REFRESH_AUTH_SUCCEEDED':
      case 'SIGN_IN_FAILED':
      case 'SIGN_OUT':
        return false;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }: Reducer<*>),
});
```

I did this because I saw that the function definition in the Redux docs was

```
combineReducers<O: Object, A>
```

But I do not fully understand why this works or know whether this is actually the right solution or makes no sense and I just got lucky. I have tried to search Google for IMPLICIT INSTANTIATIONS but I don't really find anything. I ready this article but I still dont know exactly what the return type of the call should be annotated as based on

```
combineReducers<O: Object, A>
```

Comment: Why `state` is a boolean? It should be an Object and after each case, put at least a `return Object.assign({}, state)`

Comment: I guess boolean state is OP's minimal example. I've hit same error with full-featured state, thus the bounty.

Comment: I'm a little confused if the code is using a custom written `combineReducers` function or if the default Redux one is being used. Additionally, are the [redux flow-typed annotations](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x) being used?

Comment: Let's assume defaults where possible, thus redux'es combineReduces and annotations. I can't speak for OP, but I think this question is only useful to the community if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Replace `Object` with your Object, where keys are - your state keys, and values are your reducer definition: `{status: Reducer<boolean, Action>}`

so you'll get:

`combineReducers<{status: Reducer<boolean, Action>}, Action>(...)`

**Long answer.**

`Reducer<S, any>` - reducer is a pure function which accepts current state and action and returns new state. So this is it, pretty simple. And this way it's exactly described in [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/redux_v4.x.x/flow_v0.55.x-v0.88.x/redux_v4.x.x.js#L27):

`declare export type Reducer<S, A> = (state: S | void, action: A) => S`

`$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>` - this is more complex, map over given object `O`, call each member (we expect them to be functions) and return the type. Check out the [doc](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap), it's very powerfull thing.

This part: `<S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S` might be called as `extract function type`. In human words it's might be said as -> reducer might return any type, right? So let's put reducer returned state into generic `<S>`, and then put the returned type into this [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/). I needed more then 1 day to understand how it works, hope in your case it'll be faster. :)

So finally: `combineReducer<S, A>` - given state `S` (which is Object and every member is reducer) and action `A` returns an object which members are resulted type for each call of member of `S`.

So, your `status` reducer function - could be better described as

```
Reducer<boolean, Action> //accepts boolean, Action args & return boolean
```

And we can define state as:

`type State = { status: Reducer<boolean, Action> };`

And then, pass state to combineReducer:

```
export default combineReducers<State, Action>({
    status: ((state: boolean = true, action: Action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
        case 'START_SESSION':
        case 'REFRESH_AUTH_SUCCEEDED':
        case 'SIGN_IN_FAILED':
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
            return false;
        default:
            return state;
        }
    }),
});
```

To check if typings are correct, you can import your reducer, and [cast the expressions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/):

```
const checkState = reducer({status: true}, {type: 'START_SESSION'});
(checkState.status: number); // ERROR
(checkState.status: boolean); // CORRECT
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: A very nice elaboration how the type checker works, kudos! I wish there was a "to fix the error, do this" in the answer though :)

Comment: @DimaTisnek, yeah, hard to explain it shortly... Added TLDR section